# Attachment is not working properly in node-mailer?

Tags: node.js, pdf, pdf-generation, nodemailer

Hi Am using node mailer to send mails.. It works fine with out attachment.But whenever i give some attachment it takes the default content 'data' as its content.. How should i avoid this..

My node mail function is looks like this...

```
function sendMail(toMailId, subject, body) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        email.send({
            ssl: true,
            host: DbConfig.mailConfig.host,              
            port: DbConfig.mailConfig.port,             
            domain: DbConfig.mailConfig.domain,        
            to:  DbConfig.mailConfig.to,
            from: DbConfig.mailConfig.from,
            subject: subject,
            reply_to: DbConfig.mailConfig.reply_to,
            body: body,
            authentication: DbConfig.mailConfig.authentication, 
            username: DbConfig.mailConfig.username,            
            password: DbConfig.mailConfig.password,
             attachments: [  
        {   
            filename: "helloworld.txt",
            content : 'data'    
        }   
        ],
           debug: DbConfig.mailConfig.debug                 
        },
  function (err, result) {
      if (err) { console.log(err); }
  });
    }
}
```

My problem is when i open the attachment after mail receives in my inbox, it simply shows data in the body. other than that it displays nothing. when i remove content means it throws error..

My Json will look like this:

```
{ 
 "mongodbUrl":"mongodb://USERID:PWD@localhost:27017/DBNAME",
 "mailConfig" :{
             "to":"someone@gmail.com",
             "host": "smtp.gmail.com",            
             "port": 465,                    
             "domain": "[127.0.0.1]",           
             "from":"sender@gmail.com" ,
             "subject":"This is my mail subject,
              "reply_to": "sender@gmail.com",
              "authentication": "login",       
              "username": "sender@gmail.com",         
               "password": "pswd",   
               "debug": true      

}
}
```

When i send PDF files means it is not opening.. When send text files means it is opening with the 'content data'.. how can handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using [Marak/node_mailer](https://github.com/Marak/node_mailer) instead of [andris9/Nodemailer](https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer). The first repo itself says its deprecated and points to the second one as you can see in its github page.

> Project deprecated in favor of nodemailer

You can install [Nodemailer](https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer) via

```
npm install nodemailer
```

or from the [github repo](https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer). And the exposed mailer function will be `sendMail` instead of `send`.

you can see more example of attaching files with emails in this [folder](https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer/tree/master/examples).